# Chrome Extension installed using Registry doesn't show notification popup to enable extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have msi which installs extension using windows registry as described here https://developer.chrome.com/apps/external_extensions#registry. It works fine as extension is hosted on CWS. After extension is installed, notification popup is shown to enable/remove extension.

I have created upgraded msi which contains updated nativeapp as well as new extension. When I run new msi old extension entry is removed from registry and new extension entry is added into the registry ( both extension have different ids ). At that time some times, Notification popup is not shown for newly added extension. New Extension is installed however, it is **disabled** and old extension is removed.

I event tried to restart chrome but extension notification popup is not displyed as it looks like newly added extension is blacklisted.

Is there any way so that user can be prompted with popup to enable/remove extension in this case?

Comment: Sounds like a bug in Chrome. Consider reporting on https://crbug.com.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I will report bug in Chrome.